# Как сделать копию строки с помощью целочисленной переменной?

Tags: java

К примеру, есть строка и целочисленная переменная:

```
String name = "Alex";
int num = 5;
```

И теперь каким образом можно повторить строку, чтобы получилось следующее:

```
AlexAlexAlexAlexAlex
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1235179/4928642

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Например, так:

```
String name = "Alex";
int num = 5;

StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0; i<num; i++) {
    stringBuilder.append(name);
}
String result = stringBuilder.toString();
```

В цикле `num` раз добавляете к результирующей строке заданную строку.

`StringBuilder` вместо `String` здесь используется для того, чтобы при каждой конкатенации не создавать новый объект (так как `String` является *immutable*).

В Java 8 можно получить требуемое вот так:

```
String name = "Alex";
int num = 5;
String result = String.join("", Collections.nCopies(num, name));
```

Answer (score 2):

Самый тупой способ:

```
String s = "";
for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
    s += name;
```

Comment: Нехорошо так со строками.

Comment: @post_zeew Я знаю. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, можно попробовать так:

```
String str = "hello";
int count = 10;

String result = Stream.generate(() -> str).limit(count).collect(Collectors.joining());
```